# iOS AppDelegate equivalent in Android

Tags: android, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a simple Android app with one Activity. This Activity downloads a small XML file and displays the contents to the user. Currently I kick-off the download in the Activity's `onStart` method.

It's my understanding that Activities are destroyed and re-created when the device orientation changes. So when users rotate my app the XML file is downloaded again. I'd like the app to download the file just once as it doesn't change more than a few times per day. Hence I'd like some object to retain the downloaded data so the local data can be re-used when the device orientation changes. **What's the ideal object in Android to retain the data?**

On iOS I'd use the `AppDelegate` to download the data once and retain it. Then the viewController that displays the data can just re-use the local data should it be destroyed and re-created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've seen this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Depending on the kind of data from the XML file (if it's fairly simple data), using "Shared Preferences" could be a simple way to go. You could rewrite the new data from XML when  you need to while still being able to use it from the shared preferences.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks. Is there any object in Android that has app lifecycle callbacks similar to `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, `applicationWillEnterForeground` etc?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any application callbacks other than the android activity callbacks like onStart, onResume, onPause, etc. found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Hi, see the Serviced overview https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services
The IntentService with START_REDELIVER_INTENT in onStartCommand() is what you need in case of downloading file.
I hope I have been helpful

Answer (score 32):

You have to create your own subclass of Application and specify it in the AndroidManifest.xml.
After that the new instance of this class will be created and can be accessed throughout your application.

Example:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application name="YourApp">
```

**YourApp.java**

```
public class YourApp extends Application {
    private String yourState;
 
    public void setState(String state){
        yourState = state;
    }
    public String getState(){
        return yourState;
    }
 }
```

**YourActivity.java**

```
 public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        YourApp appState = ((YourApp)getApplicationContext());// you can use getApplication() as well in the activity
        String state = appState.getState();
    }
 }
```

[More info about Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Comment: Class Cast Exception Occurred !

Comment: just to mention that `YourApp` and `YourActivity` should have `public` access

Answer (score 2):

Make your main class implement `ProcessLifecycleObserver`.

It is the equivalent of the AppDelegate in iOS as it "summarizes" activity handlers like `onCreate`, `onResume` on an app-process basis.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner

Answer (score 1):

You should be creating a model object (your own class) to retain the data on both iOS and android. imho.